# Currency formatting in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a simple setup to format currency value entered into a `TextInput` field using numeral js.
With `onChangeText` I am setting the value entered and formatting it this way

```
handleValue(value){
let amount = numeral(value).format('0,0[.]00')
// set amount 
}
```

But for some reason added decimal keep deleting itself. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me here https://snack.expo.io/9qX_VnhFn
with the decimal being placed in the correct place

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import numeral from 'numeral';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',

    },
  });
  
  const handleValue = (value) => {
    let amount = numeral(value).format('0,0[.]00');
    setValue(amount);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(value) => handleValue(value)}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          width: 280,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 4,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          paddingLeft: 15,
        }}
        value={value}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```